# Why is my forvalues loop in stata not working?

Tags: stata

I am trying to find outliers in a variable called `nbrs`, generating an interquartile (iqr) range called `nbrs_iqr`. I then want to loop (for practice with this looping concept) the values 1.5, 2, 5, and 10 in to multiply them by the iqr.

I keep getting a syntax error (invalid syntax r(198);) on the loop. I have seen something about not being able to do the forvalues loop when the values are not a range but have seen examples where it is a non-range without being explicit that that is permitted. I figured the spaces worked to separate the non-range values but I've thrown up my hands from there.

```
sum nbrs, detail
return list
gen nbrs_iqr = r(p75)-r(p25)
tab nbrs_iqr

forvalues i = 1.5 2 5 10 {
    gen nbrs_out_`i'=`i'*nbrs_iqr
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`help forvalues` is clear on the syntax you can use. Yours is not a valid *range*. You can work with `foreach`, but notice that a `.` in a variable name is not allowed.

One solution is to use `strtoname()`:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep price

sum price, detail 

gen nbrs_iqr = r(p75)-r(p25) 

foreach i of numlist 1.5 2 5 10 { 
    local newi = strtoname("`i'")
    gen nbrs_out`newi' = `i' * nbrs_iqr 
}

describe
```

My advice: familiarize yourself with `help help`.